# C# build server side ios push notification

Tags: c#, ios, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am .net developer making server side library to push notification on **IOS client application**  using FCM firebase cloud messaging using this code.

```
    {
        WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var objNotification = new
        {
            **to = "Registration token ",**
            notification = new
            {
                title = "hi",
                body = "FCM correct token tab closed"
            }
        };
        string jsonNotificationFormat = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objNotification);

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonNotificationFormat);
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "server-key"));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "sender id"));
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {

                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        String responseFromFirebaseServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                        FCMResponse response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FCMResponse>(responseFromFirebaseServer);
                        if (response.success == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Message was sent successfully");

                        }
                        else if (response.failure == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error sent from FCM server, after sending request : {0} , for following device info: {1}", responseFromFirebaseServer, jsonNotificationFormat));

                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

How could  I retrieve **Registration token** from FCM before send notification and use it to push notification ?

Thanks..

Comment: Hi. What client app would you be sending the push notifications to?

Comment: we are using IOS client app

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token